# What's the rule on using the word "git" as an alias?

Tags: bash, git, zsh, alias

I used to keep my git aliases in a file outside of my `.gitconfig` file, in the normal format of:

`alias gb="git branch --verbose"`
which worked great. But, after looking around at others' dotfiles, I thought I'd try putting them in my `.gitconfig` and see how that felt. But, I got a little hung up on how or if I can use the actual word `git` inside of the `.gitconfig` aliases.

Example:

**.gitconfig**

```
[alias]
    g = git
    a   =  add
    b   = 'branch --verbose'
```

This doesn't work (with or without the `!` in front of the `g`).

```
❯ gb
zsh: correct 'gb' to 'bg' [nyae]? n
zsh: command not found: gb
```

Now, I can put this alias in .zshrc, but it doesn't work that way either. I get the same output as above, even after reloading my shell.

```
alias g='git'
```

Are people manually typing out `git a`, etc. every time?

Comment: I'm looking for a better solution for this as well. Ideally you could use `alias g="git "` (with that trailing space) and then run `gs` and the `s` would be interpreted by the git aliases. Unfortunately aliases with trailing whitespace mean search other aliases for any other passed characters/arguments. Trying to find a way around this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Are people manually typing out git a?

Yes.

Or you can define a shell alias (in addition of your git alias)

```
git alias b='branch --verbose'
alias gb="git b"
```

Comment: I wonder why you can't this do in a file that isn't .gitconfig:         

`````
    alias g="git "
    alias a="add"

Comment: @KevinSuttle if this isn't in a `.gitconfig`, that means it is a shell alias. And shell alias works with a complete command, not the composition of two separate commands/parameters. `alias gb` or `alias ga` is fine (and can be defined in a `.profile` or `.bashrc`).